# Is there anyway for backend to send respond without a request with a dialogflow with it?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, dialogflow-es, backend, dialogflow-es-fulfillment

I have a question, for example my app have a daily challenges trough chats. How can I automate the message send from backend to the chat and make sure that this chat will go to specific intent that we have defined before? Because from what I understand a chat will go to specific intent after it gets the trigger words.

Comment: You can use dialogflow event

Answer (score 0):

**Invoke events with fulfillment**

You can invoke events via fulfillment by setting the `followupEventInput` field of the `WebhookResponse`. You can optionally set the `followupEventInput.parameters` field to provide parameters to the intent.

```
agent.setFollowupEvent('SOME_EVENT');

  // OR //
{
  "followupEventInput": {
    "name": "event-name",
    "parameters": {
      "parameter-name-1": "parameter-value-1",
      "parameter-name-2": "parameter-value-2"
    },
    "languageCode": "en-US"
  }
}
```

When the `followupEventInput` parameter is set for a `WebhookResponse`, Dialogflow ignores the `fulfillmentText`, `fulfillmentMessages`, and `payload` fields. When Dialogflow receives a webhook response that includes an `event`, it immediately triggers the corresponding `intent` in which it was defined.

Comment: How can we define the event in dialogflow using webhook? Can you share the documentation for it and maybe a code example of it.

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/docs/events-overview

Comment: Hi, can you explain a little bit more about whats the the difference between fulfillment and API? I think right now I am using fullfilemtn now. so is it like inside @forintent, you put like respondBuilder.followupEventInput({
      name:"test"
      parameter:{}
}) something like that ? [codepen](https://codepen.io/farhankhalifa/pen/pogpxMP)

maybe you could share the code in codepen how to use fulfillment event. Thank you

Comment: https://github.com/dialogflow/dialogflow-fulfillment-nodejs/issues/102

Comment: Thanks, but actually as you see from the diagram in github, the user has to send some request first which in this case is a chat inside the app. but what I want is the dialogflow or backend send a message first and it is already known to which intent this conversation will go.

Comment: what is the channel, your dialogflow is connected with ?

Comment: you can store the session of user and respond them with specific session.The terminology is user engagement. In google action you can do is with push notifications, with facebook you can achive with sender id

Comment: I am having my own chat app, so we are not using any message provider given by dialogflow. Is possible to do it? also, isn't that with push notification we are not able to make sure that the chat will go to the intent that we want to?

Comment: If you are using your own chat and want to send message, user must be connected with your server via socket